# Update values of a Symfony form dynamically

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony5

On Symfony 5, I try to update value of 4 inputs depending of a select option using :

`$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) { });`

I get an error: 422 and a wonderful **Message: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.** Hard to resubmit an Ajax request...

Can u help me ?

**In controller:**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/new", name="location_new", methods={"GET","POST"})
     */
    public function new(Request $request): Response
    {
        $location = new Location();
        $form = $this->createForm(LocationType::class, $location);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($location);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('location_index', [], Response::HTTP_SEE_OTHER);
        }

        return $this->renderForm('location/new.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

**In template file**

```
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ form_row(form.submit) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-4"/>
{{ form_end(form) }}
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var $type = $('#location_type');
    var $name = $('#location_name');
    var $code = $('#location_code');
    var $project = $('#location_project');
    
    $type.prop("disabled", true);
    
    var NameCodeChange = function() {
        if(!$name.val().trim() && !$code.val().trim()) $type.prop("disabled", true);
        else $type.prop("disabled", false);
    };

    $name.change(NameCodeChange);
    $code.change(NameCodeChange);
    
    $type.change(function() {
        if(console) console.log('location type changed : ' + $type.val());
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};
        data[$name.attr('name')] = $name.val();
        data[$code.attr('name')] = $code.val();
        data[$type.attr('name')] = $type.val();
        data[$project.attr('name')] = $project.val();

        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            complete: function(html) {

                $('#location_ip').replaceWith(
                    $(html.responseText).find('#location_ip')
                );
                $('#location_ik').replaceWith(
                    $(html.responseText).find('#location_ik')
                );
                $('#location_tMin').replaceWith(
                    $(html.responseText).find('#location_tMin')
                );
                $('#location_tMax').replaceWith(
                    $(html.responseText).find('#location_tMax')
                );
                $('#location_lux').replaceWith(
                    $(html.responseText).find('#location_lux')
                );
            }
        });
    });
    if(console) console.log('loaded');
});

</script>
```

**In EntityType (buildForm method)**

```
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            \dump($event);
            
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $data = $event->getData();
            if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
                return;
            }
            if (!array_key_exists('type', $data)) {
                return;
            }
            
            $type = $data['type'];
            
            $locationType = $this->locationTypeRepository->find($type);
            if($locationType == null) return;
            /*
            $form->get('ip')->setData($locationType->getIp());
            $form->get('ik')->setData($locationType->getIk());
            $form->get('tMin')->setData($locationType->getTMin());
            $form->get('tMax')->setData($locationType->getTMax());
            $form->get('lux')->setData($locationType->getLux());
            */
            
            $form->add('ip', null, [
                'data' => $locationType->getIp(),
            ])
                ->add('ik', null, [
                'data' => $locationType->getIk(),
            ])
            ->add('tMin', IntegerType::class, [
                'attr' => array(
                    'min' => -100,
                    'max' => 30,
                    'step' => 5,
                ),
                'data' => $locationType->getTMin(),
             ])
             ->add('tMax', IntegerType::class, [
                'attr' => array(
                    'min' => 30,
                    'max' => +100,
                    'step' => 5,
             
                ),
                'data' => $locationType->getTMax(),
             ])
             ->add('lux', IntegerType::class, [
                'attr' => array(
                    'min' => 5,
                    'step' => 5,
                ),
                'data' => $locationType->getLux(),
             ]);
        });
```

I tried differents FormEvents but never get a HTTP:200... T_T

Comment: Try submitting the `_token` field of the form along with your `data` object.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct that you have to submit the `_token`, but since you are submitting a specific form here, Symfony expects a specific form field name for the token. The selector depends on the object's class name for which form is used.

In your case, it is `Location` so you should have field with ID `location__token` (two underscores).

Following your current code structure, you could define a variable:

```js
var $token = $('#location__token');
```

And then add additional element to your data set:

```js
data[$token.attr('name')] = $token.val();
```

Also, use event type `POST_SUBMIT` instead of `POST_SET_DATA`, because you are submitting the form and fields that you want to add dynamically depend on the submitted values (basically, your `locationType`).

Please refer to Symfony documentation for detailed example:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Finally, keep in mind that you are submitting the form. So your controller checks if form is submitted and if it is valid, even before user can select all of the fields and would even try to prematurely create the database entry.

To bypass this, you can send some extra parameter when doing the Ajax request, check it in your controller and do not check for form submission and validation, if parameter is submitted. Example:

```php
$country_change = $request->request->get('country_change');
if (!$country_change && $form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    ...
}
```